# Problems about protocol and drawing in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drawing

I want to define a Symbol protocol and write three different structs, Rectangle, Diamond and Oval. The first two are OK, but Oval returns UIBezierPath instead of Path. What should I do

```swift
//
//  Symbol.swift
//  Set
//
//  Created by world on 2022/11/27.
//

import SwiftUI

protocol Symbol: Shape {
    var numberOfSymbols: SetGame.Card.Number { get }
    func drawing(_ path: Path, center: CGPoint, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> Path
}

extension Symbol {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let widthOfRect = rect.maxX - rect.minX
        let heightOfRect = rect.maxY - rect.minY
        let widthOfSymbol = widthOfRect
        let heightOfSymbol = widthOfSymbol / 2
        var path = Path()
        switch numberOfSymbols {
        case .one:
            path = drawing(path, center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), width: widthOfSymbol, height: heightOfSymbol)
        case .two:
            path = drawing(path, center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: heightOfRect * 1/3), width: widthOfSymbol, height: heightOfSymbol)
            path = drawing(path, center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: heightOfRect * 2/3), width: widthOfSymbol, height: heightOfSymbol)
        case .three:
            path = drawing(path, center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: heightOfRect * 1/4), width: widthOfSymbol, height: heightOfSymbol)
            path = drawing(path, center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: heightOfRect * 2/4), width: widthOfSymbol, height: heightOfSymbol)
            path = drawing(path, center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: heightOfRect * 3/4), width: widthOfSymbol, height: heightOfSymbol)
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

This is the diamond part that has been implemented

result: [Diamond Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgc8e.png)

```swift
//
//  Diamond.swift
//  Set
//
//  Created by world on 2022/11/27.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Diamond: Symbol {
    var numberOfSymbols: SetGame.Card.Number
    
    func drawing(_ path: Path, center: CGPoint, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> Path {
        var path = path
        let rightPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x + width/2, y: center.y)
        path.move(to: rightPoint)
        let bottomPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y + height/2)
        let leftPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x - width/2 , y: center.y)
        let topPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y - height/2)
        path.addLine(to: bottomPoint)
        path.addLine(to: leftPoint)
        path.addLine(to: topPoint)
        path.addLine(to: rightPoint)
        return path
    }
}
```

I haven't implemented the oval part yet

```swift
//
//  Oval.swift
//  Set
//
//  Created by world on 2022/11/27.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Oval: Symbol {
    var numberOfSymbols: SetGame.Card.Number
    
    func drawing(_ path: Path, center: CGPoint, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> Path {
        var path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: 0)
// ...
    }
}
```

Perhaps this can be solved by function overloading

Comment: You can for example convert `UIBezierPath` to `Path` via `cgPath` property (i.e. `Path(UIBezierPath(...).cgPath)`)

Comment: It worked

`path.addPath(
            Path(
                UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: center.x-width/2, y: center.y-height/2, width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: 60).cgPath
            )
        )`